# Throw exception if a service is not running when it should be?

Tags: exception, windows-services

If you are writing a piece of code to check the availability of a windows service, and ideally it should be available (from a monitoring/availability perspective), but isn't, would this classify as an "exceptional" even for which to throw an exception for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strong rule: A routine should throw an exception if and only if it cannot meet its documented post-conditions.  There is some flexibility in how post-conditions are defined, though.  The way in which post-conditions are defined will determine whether a routine should throw and exception.

If certain problem conditions are foreseeable, it may be useful to have separate methods for:

1. Determining in advance whether something is likely to work

   Attempting to do something, and indicating via return code whether it worked

   Do something with the expectation that it will work, throwing an exception if it doesn't

If the only thing the caller of a routine would be able to do in case of failure is throw an exception, would likely be better to have one piece of code inside the routine to check the condition and throw the exception, than require such code to be duplicated in each caller.  On the other hand, if a caller will be prepared to deal with an error (e.g. using some kind or retry or search-elsewhere strategy) it would be better to have the routine return an error code than throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Only if your method relies on that service in order to return properly.

Answer (score 0):

And only if you have something the catch that exception and knows how to handle it....

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the phrase

> **ideally** it should be available (from a monitoring/availability perspective)

strongly suggests that the service in question is not essential to the functionality of the method you are writing.

If this is so, the condition is one for which generating a warning event rather than throwing an exception may be the appropriate action.